# fail to install module PIL - error - Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PI

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

when trying to import - `from PIL import Image` this error occurs:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PIL
```

Comment: `from PIL import Image` will never make such an error... Maybe `pip install PIL` would...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the solution:

```
pip install Pillow
```

after that make sure it works:

```
from PIL import Image
```